# SQL Select Bottom Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I wish to retrieve the oldest X records.  At present my query is something like the following:

```
SELECT Id, Title, Comments, CreatedDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreatedDate > @OlderThanDate
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

I know that normally I would remove the 'DESC' keyword to switch the order of the records, however in this instance I still want to get records ordered with the newest item first.

So I want to know if there is any means of performing this query such that I get the oldest X items sorted such that the newest item is first.  I should also add that my database exists on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not just use a subquery?

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM
(SELECT TOP X Id, Title, Comments, CreatedDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreatedDate > @OlderThanDate
ORDER BY CreatedDate) T1
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Embed the query. You take the top x when sorted in ascending order (i.e. the oldest) and then re-sort those in descending order ...

```
select * 
from 
(
    SELECT top X Id, Title, Comments, CreatedDate
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE CreatedDate > @OlderThanDate
    ORDER BY CreatedDate 
) a
order by createddate desc
```